# Cannot Retrieve Column[0] in a Gridview

Tags: c#

I have been able to correctly access every column/row combination in my grid, except for column 1. It always returns a blank. Below is 4 different ways I have tried, they all run, but all return blank.

```cs
protected void userListGrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Display") //switch to update user mode
    {
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        string Username = userListGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
        // LinkButton Link = userListGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
        // string Username3 = Link.Text;
        string Username4 = userListGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text.ToString();

        GridViewRow selectedRow = userListGrid.Rows[rowIndex];
        TableCell lastNameCell = selectedRow.Cells[0];
        string lastName = lastNameCell.Text; 

        List<CustomUserRecord> userRoleList = GetUserList(Username);
    }
}
```

So  I am trying to get the column user ID

```
User ID | Email
Jack    | Jack@gmail
Diane   | Diana@aol.com
```

Comment: By first you mean that Index of collection is 0? If so then ir might be header.

Comment: @Carl By first I mean Column[0]. So if I look at row 5, column(1) I get the 2nd column data, if I look at Column(0) I get a blank, naturally (-1) is an error

Comment: That is exactly what I was referring to. First collection item that is being returned is actually a header of your grid's column.

Comment: Is that column editable?... what do you get directly from getting the cell? I mean `userListGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0]`... maybe the value is not in the `Text` Prop, If the the cell is not a `Text` Cell, the value may be within another prop or control...

Comment: With .Text I get "" , with ToString() I get "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell" ... When I do .Text for all other columns it returns the correct result, just not column 0 (User ID)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this. Probably would have got help but I didn't realize it was a Linkbutton sorry all, thanks for your help.

```
 int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
 LinkButton Link = (LinkButton)userListGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0] ;
                string Username = Link.Text;
```